# new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { … }); コンストラクタ内で、resolve または reject を呼び出す時の挙動について

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

**コード**

```
"use strict";
var pObj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  reject('テスト');
})
console.log(pObj);
```

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: "テスト"}
>   Uncaught (in promise) テスト

---

**疑問＆質問**
・reject('テスト');が実行されるタイミングは？
・promiseオブジェクトが作成される前、それともpromiseオブジェクト作成後に実行？
・Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: は"pending"後"rejected"？ それとも最初から"rejected"なのでしょうか？

---

**確認しようと思ったけれどもうまくいかなかったコード**

```
"use strict";
pObj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log("1");
  //console.log(pObj);
  reject('テスト');
  console.log("2");
  console.log(pObj);
})
console.log("3");
console.log(pObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECMA Script 2015 の仕様書の `Promise(executor)` の記述](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor) に従うと、回答は以下のとおりになります。

> reject('テスト');が実行されるタイミングは？

`Promise(executor)` の実行中です。

> promiseオブジェクトが作成される前、それともpromiseオブジェクト作成後に実行？

利用する観点では、作成される(完了する)前です。厳密に言うと作成中ですね。

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: は"pending"後"rejected"？ それとも最初から"rejected"なのでしょうか？

利用する観点では、最初から `rejected` です。厳密には、内部状態として `pending` 後に `rejected` になっていると考えられますが、それを観測する手段はないでしょう。